# How I convert pine script v5?

Tags: pine-script

```
calc_csf(src, length) => 
    sm = 2.0/length
    csf=(src - nz(csf[1])) * sm + nz(csf[1])
    csf
```

I must convert this function to v5 but I get this error:

> Undeclared identifier 'csf'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot self reference variables anymore starting from `v3`.

You should write it as below:

```
calc_csf(src, length) => 
    csf = 0.0
    sm = 2.0/length
    csf :=(src - nz(csf[1])) * sm + nz(csf[1])
    csf
```

Please read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_3.html) to know the other changes and how you can upgrade your code to `v5`.

The easiest thing to do is upgrade it to `v3` yourself and then use the converter tool for the rest.